# Populating JList,attribute of class with JFrame from a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a MainForm class that extends JFrame and has a JList in it.

Now on clicking a button a JDialog pops up, to enter credentials, which in turn downloads a list of values which is to be populated in the Jlist of the parent window.

Now how do I populate my mainForm attribute from my child class ?

MainForm.java

```
public class MainForm extends JFrame {

static MainForm mainForm;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainForm = new MainForm();
            mainForm.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

    public MainForm() {
               loadUI();
    }

    private void loadUI() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);

            final JList<String> jList = new JList<String>();

            final JButton settings = new JButton(settingImage);
    settings.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3, 0, 3, 0));
    settings.setBounds(50, 60, 100, 30);
    vertical.add(settings);

    settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             LoginDialog loginDlg = new LoginDialog(mainForm);
             loginDlg.setVisible(true);
             // if logon successfully
             if(loginDlg.isSucceeded()){
                 settings.setText("Hi " + loginDlg.getUsername() + "!");
             }
        }
    });

            add(vertical, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(jList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

DialogWindow.java

```
    public LoginDialog(final Frame parent) {
    super(parent, "Login", true);
    //
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    //some more lines of code

    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               ftpAuthenticationVO.setIp(urlIP.getText());
                    ftpAuthenticationVO.setUsername(tfUsername.getText());
                    ftpAuthenticationVO.setPassword(pfPassword.getText());
                    FileUtils.saveFTPDetails(ftpAuthenticationVO);
                    if(ftpConnect.startFTP(CommonConstants.TEMP_TXT_FILE));
                    {
                        List<String> list = readSplitTextFiles.readTextFile(CommonConstants.TEMP_TXT_FILE);
                    //This is the value that is to be populated in the Jlist inside the parent window.  
                    }
```

Comment: Are you referencing the JList in your action listener? e.g. jlist.add(value) etc.

Comment: In `MainWindow` you have `LoginDialog loginDlg = new LoginDialog(mainForm,jList);`, but `LoginDialog`  constructor you show us, takes only a **single** parameter. So which way is it?

Comment: jlist.add(value), how do i get the value of list from the JDialog, after the JDialog is closed ?
My MainForm just calls the constructor of LoginDialog class.

Comment: i just edited. I was trying something and that must have being left there.

Comment: What exactly is `mainForm`?

Comment: one more edit..please have a look. Sorry for the messy code

Answer (score 2):

Just make your JList as attribute of the `MainForm`

```
public class MainForm extends JFrame {

private JList jlist;

.
.
.

private void loadUI() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    jList = new JList<String>();

    final JButton settings = new JButton(settingImage);
    settings.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3, 0, 3, 0));
    settings.setBounds(50, 60, 100, 30);
    vertical.add(settings);
    .
    .
}


public void setJListModel(List<String> list){
   jlist.setModel(new Vector(list));
}

}
```

And in JDialog

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               ftpAuthenticationVO.setIp(urlIP.getText());
                    ftpAuthenticationVO.setUsername(tfUsername.getText());
                    ftpAuthenticationVO.setPassword(pfPassword.getText());
                    FileUtils.saveFTPDetails(ftpAuthenticationVO);
                    if(ftpConnect.startFTP(CommonConstants.TEMP_TXT_FILE));
                    {
                        List<String> list = readSplitTextFiles.readTextFile(CommonConstants.TEMP_TXT_FILE);
 (MainForm)parent.setJListModel(list);
                    }
```

Also parent must be declared as `final`.